# Diverging Implicits for Case Class w/ Case Class Argument

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the following from Travis Brown's educational and well-written [Type classes and generic derivation](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/):

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Double)

 trait Parser[A] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[A]
  }

  implicit val hnilParser: Parser[HNil] = new Parser[HNil] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[HNil] = if(s.isEmpty) Some(HNil) else None
  }

  implicit def hconsParser[H: Parser, T <: HList: Parser]: Parser[H :: T] = new Parser[H :: T] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[H :: T] = s.split(",").toList match {
      case cell +: rest => for {
        head <- implicitly[Parser[H]].apply(cell)
        tail <- implicitly[Parser[T]].apply(rest.mkString(","))
      } yield head :: tail
    }
  }

  implicit val stringParser: Parser[String] = new Parser[String] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[String] = Some(s)
  }

  implicit val intParser: Parser[Int] = new Parser[Int] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption
  }

  implicit val doubleParser: Parser[Double] = new Parser[Double] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[Double] = Try(s.toDouble).toOption
  }

  implicit val booleanParser: Parser[Boolean] = new Parser[Boolean] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[Boolean] = Try(s.toBoolean).toOption
  }

  implicit def caseClassParser[A, R <: HList](implicit gen: Generic[A] { type Repr = R },
                                              reprParser: Parser[R]): Parser[A] =
    new Parser[A] {
      def apply(s: String): Option[A] = reprParser.apply(s).map(gen.from)
    }


  object Parser {
    def apply[A](s: String)(implicit parser: Parser[A]): Option[A] = parser(s)
  }

  implicit val stringParser: Parser[String] = new Parser[String] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[String] = Some(s)
  }

  implicit val intParser: Parser[Int] = new Parser[Int] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[Int] = Try(s.toInt).toOption
  }

  implicit val doubleParser: Parser[Double] = new Parser[Double] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[Double] = Try(s.toDouble).toOption
  }
```

I was curious to try to get a `Parser[X]` where `X` is a case class with a `Person` argument, i.e. a case class:

```
case class PersonWrapper(person: Person, x: Int)
```

Yet I get an error:

```
scala> Parser[PersonWrapper]("kevin,66,42")
<console>:15: error: diverging implicit expansion for type net.Test.Parser[net.Test.PersonWrapper]
starting with method caseClassParser in object Test
       Parser[PersonWrapper]("kevin,66,42")
                            ^
```

First, why does this divergent implicit error occur?

Secondly, is it possible to use the above code to get a `Parser[PersonWrapper]`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some implicit hanging around in the REPL scope? I don't get the diverging implicit error.

Comment: Hmm. Well, what result do you get with `Parser[PersonWrapper]("kevin, 66,42")`? Here's my full result: https://gist.github.com/kevinmeredith/f4995cdf3bc61907bef76182bee69b39

Answer (score 1):

> Secondly, is it possible to use the above code to get a Parser[PersonWrapper]?

No, just skip to the end of the article:

> ```
> scala> case class BookBook(b1: Book, b2: Book)
> defined class BookBook
>
> scala> Parser[BookBook]("Hamlet,Shakespeare")
>   res7: Option[BookBook] = None
> ```
>
> Our format doesn’t support any kind of nesting (at least we haven’t said anything about nesting, and it wouldn’t be trivial), so we don’t actually know how to parse a string into a BookBook...

The problem is that `cell` in `case cell +: rest` will only ever be a string with no commas that is passed to `implicitly[Parser[H]].apply(cell)`. For `PersonWrapper`, this means that the very first cell will attempt to do this:

```
implicitly[Parser[PersonWrapper]].apply("kevin")
```

Which will obviously fail to parse. In order to get nested parsers to work, you would need some way to group the cells together prior to applying a `Parser[H]` to them.